# How can I implement scrollbar-track color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to add track color for my flutter project but is not work for me also when i try to give thumbcolor it is work !!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try to add this to your material App:**

```
 theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData().copyWith(
      thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[500]),
    )
```

**OR**
Scroll bar uses the highlight color, so just add your desired scrollbar color in the highlightColor inside Theme in MaterialApp:

```
highlightColor: Colors.red
```

Comment: just change thumbColor it is not work for track color

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```dart
Theme(
  scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
    thumbColor: ...
    trackColor: ...
  ),
)
```

Comment: just change thumbColor it is not work for track color